# Using findContours in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, contour, threshold

I'm using OpenCV on the raspberry pi and building with Python.  Trying to make a simple object tracker that uses color to find the object by thresholding the image and finding the contours to locate the centroid.  When I use the following code:

```
image=frame.array
imgThresholded=cv2.inRange(image,lower,upper)    
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(imgThresholded,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt=contours[0]
Moments = cv2.moments(cnt)
Area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "realtime.py", line 122, in <module>
  cnt=contours[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried a few other settings and get the same error or

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I'm using the PiCamera.  Any suggestions for getting centroid position?

Thanks

Z

Answer (score 3):

## Error 1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "realtime.py", line 122, in <module>
  cnt=contours[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Simply stands that the `cv2.findContours()` method didn't found any contours in the given image, so it is always suggested to do a sanity checking before accessing the contour, as:

```
if len(contours) > 0:
    # Processing here.
else:
    print "Sorry No contour Found."
```

## Error2

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

This error is raised due to `_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours`, since the `cv2.findContours` returns only 2 values, contours and hierarchy, So obviously when you try to unpack 3 values from 2 element tuple returned by the `cv2.findContours`, it would raise the above mentioned error.

Also the `cv2.findContours` changes the input mat in place, so it is suggested to call the `cv2.findContours` as:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgThresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
if len(contours) > 0:
    # Processing here.
else:
    print "Sorry No contour Found."
```